# How can I reduce the file size of a .mov video created with AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am able to record a video using `AVCaptureSession`.But i want to
reduce it size.How can i do this ? I am getting final `URL` in Delegate
"captureOutput" method.

```
    VideoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    VideoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error]; 
    if (!error) 
    { 
        if ([CaptureSession canAddInput:VideoInputDevice]) 
        {
            [CaptureSession addInput:VideoInputDevice]; 
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input"); 
        } 
    else 
    { 
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input"); 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device"); 
} 

AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
```

Comment: Can you show how you record and save?

Comment: VideoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
 
  VideoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:VideoDevice error:&error];
  if (!error)
  {
   if ([CaptureSession canAddInput:VideoInputDevice])
    [CaptureSession addInput:VideoInputDevice];
   else
    NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
  }
  else
  {
   NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
  }
 }
 else
 {
  NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
 }
 
 AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

Comment: I will edit that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an AVAssetExportSession. You code will look something like this:

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:myAsset presetName:exportPreset];

exporter.videoComposition = _videoComposition;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = NO;
url = [url URLByAppendingPathExtension:CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)(exporter.outputFileType), kUTTagClassFilenameExtension))];
exporter.outputURL = url;

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    // handle the completion in a way meaningful to your app
}];
```

You export preset should be one of these:

```
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset640x480           NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset960x540           NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset1280x720          NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080         NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0);
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160         NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, NA);
```

Comment: yes I tried this...After this compression the video size is too low

Comment: Surely ONE of the presets gives you a size you want. How big is your video (Both in width/height and length and MB) and how big do you want it to be? Why do you need it to be smaller? What are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this method will be helpful for u

```
- (void)compressingVideoWithSoundWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL andResolution:(CGSize)resolution
{
    self.myVideoWriter = nil;

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];

    //setup video writer
    AVAsset *videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:inputURL options:nil];

    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDictionary *videoWriterCompressionSettings =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1250000], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey, nil];

    NSDictionary *videoWriterSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey, videoWriterCompressionSettings, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:resolution.width], AVVideoWidthKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:resolution.height], AVVideoHeightKey, nil];

    AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                            assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                            outputSettings:videoWriterSettings];

    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

    videoWriterInput.transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform;


    NSError* writerError = nil;

    self.myVideoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:outputURL fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&writerError];

    if (writerError) {
        NSLog(@"Writer error: %@", writerError);
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"VideoEditor. compressingVideoWithInputURL: outputURL: andResolution:. Writer error: %@", writerError];
        FLog(message);
        return;
    }



    [self.myVideoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

    //setup video reader
    NSDictionary *videoReaderSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

    AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *videoReaderOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:videoReaderSettings];

    AVAssetReader *videoReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset error:nil];

    [videoReader addOutput:videoReaderOutput];

    //setup audio writer
    AVAssetWriterInput* audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                            assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                            outputSettings:nil];

    audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;

    [self.myVideoWriter addInput:audioWriterInput];

    //setup audio reader
    AVAssetTrack* audioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

    AVAssetReaderOutput *audioReaderOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:audioTrack outputSettings:nil];

    AVAssetReader *audioReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:videoAsset error:nil];

    [audioReader addOutput:audioReaderOutput];

    [self.myVideoWriter startWriting];

    //start writing from video reader
    [videoReader startReading];

    [self.myVideoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    dispatch_queue_t processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("processingQueue1", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    [videoWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:processingQueue usingBlock:
     ^{

         while ([videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {

             CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer;

             if ([videoReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading &&
                 (sampleBuffer = [videoReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer])) {

                 [videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                 CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
             }

             else {

                 [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];

                 if ([videoReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted) {
                     if ([audioReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading || [audioReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted) {

                     }
                     else{
                         //start writing from audio reader
                         [audioReader startReading];

                         [self.myVideoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

                         dispatch_queue_t processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("processingQueue2", NULL);

                         [audioWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:processingQueue usingBlock:^{

                             while (audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {

                                 CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer;

                                 if ([audioReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading &&
                                     (sampleBuffer = [audioReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer])) {

                                     [audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                                     CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                                 }
                                 else {

                                     [audioWriterInput markAsFinished];

                                     if ([audioReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted)
                                     {
                                         [self finishWritingAction];
                                         break;
                                     }

                                 }
                             }

                         }
                          ];
                     }
                 }

             }
         }
     }
     ];
}
```